# What is the meaning of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$, sheldon axler problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Sheldon Axler, linear algebra done right, 3rd edition.

Exercise 24 of the C section

Show that:

$\mathbb{R} ^ \mathbb{R}   = U_e  \oplus U_o$ with $U_e$ the set of all even valued functions and $U_o$ the set set of uneven functions.

I have the solution (found here: https://linearalgebras.com/1c.html), but I don't really get what $\mathbb{R} ^ \mathbb{R}$ means? Usually they mean dimensions with it, but what's the meaning of $\mathbb{R} $ dimensions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's important to note that while the exponent gives the dimension when it's finite, this is false for infinite exponents (look into, for instance, the difference between direct products and direct sums)

Answer (score 2):

$\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ means the set of all functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$

In general, $A^B$ means the set of all functions from $B$ to $A$. Also the notation is somewhat meaningful, since one can understand the cardinality by $$\vert A^B \vert=\vert A\vert^{\vert B \vert}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ is a notation meaning "the set of all functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$".

To understand this notation of $F^E$, meaning the set of functions from set $E$ to set $F$, you can think of $E^n$ which is the set of $n$-uplets of elements of $E$. In other words it's a set where each element is made of any $n$ values picked from $E$.

Likewise $E^{\Bbb N}$ is the set of integer indexed sequences of elements of $E$. Each element is a sequence of elements of $E$. In other words, an element of $E^{\Bbb N}$ is equivalent to picking a specific value from $E$ for each integer, that is, a function from $\Bbb N$ to $E$.

Finally, we can extend this idea to any set, including $\Bbb R$ : to create an element $f$ of $\Bbb R ^{\Bbb R}$, you pick a value $f(x)$ in $\Bbb R$ for each $x \in \Bbb R$, i.e a real-valued function.